# What is the difference between these two bits of code? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, apply

I'm trying to figure out what the difference between the following two snippets of code. They both flatten an array of subarrays and both output the same thing.

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        subArray.forEach(function(element) {
            results.push(element);
        });
    });

    return results;
}; // [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push.apply(results, subArray);
    });

    return results;
}; // [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

How does apply work? Why does it `results` have to be written twice?

Answer (score 1):

`apply` is a method of a function, allowing to pass explicit `this` argument (which may differ from the object the function is a member of) and array of arguments. In your example `apply` is used for its ability to accept array of arguments, as a substitute for [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).